# fixed header jumps on scroll down (android/windows phone)

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I have fixed header, but when I scroll down this header scrolls with a bit delay(hide and then jumps in right position), on iOS I fixed it with **transform: translate3d(0,0,0);** but on Android and Windows Phone It's not working and still jumps, can you help me to fix it, please?

html

`<header class="header">
        <div class="header-top">
            <div class="header-top-in">
                <div class="container"> 
                 'content'
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="js-header-scroll header--translate">
        <div class="header-bottom">
            <div class="header-bottom-in">
                <div class="container">
                   'content'
                 </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          </div>
    </header>`

CSS

```
    .header {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 9999;
        display: block;
    }
    header .header-top {
        background: #1d7bcd;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 600;
    }
    .header--fixed {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     z-index: 999;
   }
   .header--translate {
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
   }

    header .header-bottom {
        background: #4192d9;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 500;
    }
    header .header-bottom .header-bottom-in {
        height: 60px;
        position: relative;
    }
      .container {
   width: 1240px;
   padding: 0 20px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   position: relative;
   }
```

jQuery

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 40) {
        $('.js-header-scroll').addClass('header--fixed');

    } else {
        $('.js-header-scroll').removeClass('header--fixed');

    }
});
```

ps: I need being fixed only bottom part of header, header-top is static

Comment: why you add it later? use position:fixed from the start

Comment: I need being fixed only bottom part of header

Comment: .js-header-scroll{postion:fixed;} in css file, this doesnt work?

Comment: I added this in css and header-bottom scrolls down on height of header-top and then jumps on top where it should be

Comment: can you create a fiddle with your code? so we can see a running examle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/youfka/q4n02u6e/ I can't see it there, but when I scroll very slowly on android it's fine, when I scroll faster it jumps